# Consider the set of matrices $2 \times 2$ whose dash is zero, i.e. U = {$A ​\in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R) \vert tr(A) = 0$}. Show that...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Consider the set of matrices $2 \times 2$ whose dash is zero, i.e.
> U = {$A ​​\in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R) \vert tr(A) = 0$}.Show that $U$ is a subspace of $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R)$ and find a basis for $U$.

My attempt

$tr(A) = 0 = a_{11}+a_{22}$
$A_{2 \times 2} + B_{2 \times 2} = [a_{11}+b_{11}, a_{12}+b_{12}, a_{21}+b_{21}, a_{22}+b_{22}] = [a_{11}+b_{11}, a_{12}+b_{12}, a_{21}+b_{21}, (-a_{11}-b_{11})] \to a_{11}+b_{11}+ (-a_{11}-b_{11}) = 0$

$\alpha A = [\alpha a_{11}, \alpha a_{12}, \alpha a_{21}, \alpha a_{22}] \to \alpha (a_{11} + a_{22}) = \alpha 0 = 0$

b={[1, 0, 0, 0], [0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,-1]}

linear independence

$\alpha [1, 0, 0, 0], \beta [0,1,0,0], \gamma [0,0,1,0], \omega [0,0,0,-1] = [\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \omega] = [0,0,0,0] \to \alpha = \beta = \gamma \omega = 0$

$[a,b,c,-a] = a [1, 0, 0, 0], b [0,1,0,0], c [0,0,1,0], d [0,0,0,-1] = [a,b,c,-a]$

Correct?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Replace the word "dash" by "trace". 2) Your proof that $U$ si a subspace may be considered as correct (though sloppy). 3) Your $b$ is a basis of $M_{2,2}$, not of $U$ (its first and last elements don't belong to $U$). 4) Your proof of independence of $b$ is not correct (3 $+$, 1 $-$ and 1 $=$ are missing). 5) Your last line of equations is rather mysterious (more generaly, write sentences between your formulas).

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately the basis is going to have to be $3$ dimensional (not $4$).

So, you could go with $\{\begin {pmatrix}1\quad 0\\0\quad -1\end {pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix}0\quad 1\\0\quad 0\end {pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix}0\quad 0\\1\quad 0\end {pmatrix}\}$.

Your proposed basis vectors don't all have trace zero (so can't be right).  That's if I'm reading you right (which is a big if).

Answer (score 0):

*Alternatively*, you may like to use the one-liner test as follows:
Let $A,B\in U$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$. 
Then $\alpha A+\beta B\in U$; 
$\because tr(\alpha A+\beta B)=tr(\alpha A)+tr(\beta B)=\alpha. tr(A)+\beta. tr(B)=0$
Hence $U$ is a subspace of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0):

Almost, but not quite. Your proof that $U$ is a subspace is correct, but your suggested basis is wrong. In fact, you can immediately know that it is wrong, because your basis has 4 vectors (matrices), whereas $U$, being a strict subspace of a 4-dimentional space, must be strictly less than 4-dimentional.

Your suggested basis is actually very close to correct, and you have the right idea, but you implemented it wrong. To be a basis for $U$, each of you basis vectors $b_1, ... , b_4$ must at the very least satisfy the defining property of $U$. The vectors $b_2$ and $b_3$ do, however $b_1$ and $b_4$ don't, and in fact (which is where you had the right intuition) $b_1$ and $b_4$ have opposite traces. Thus, since the trace is linear, all you need to do is combine them into a single vector $\hat{b} = b_1+b_4$, and you'll have your basis.

Comment: Right,  not all matrices have trace zero.   So the subspace can't have dimension $4$.  It's easy to find $3$ linearly independent matrices that do though.   And thus any such three form a basis.